# how to use floating action button with navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, floating-action-button

I'm new at programming and I want to use Navigation Drawer with `FloatingActionButton`. I'm able to make both of these separately but I can't do it in a single project.
I don't really want to 3rd party libraries.

Edit:

I want to use Navigation Drawer and `FloatingActionButton` for opening different fragments.
By default, this is the Navigation Drawer and I need to add action to the `FloatingActionB`

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

app_bar_main.xml(which has floating button)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_radio" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage" />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
```

Comment: what do you actually want a button in navigation drawer along with list ?

Comment: I'm practicing and I want to use Navigation bar which can open fragments and a FAB which can also open some fragments.

Comment: Hey @Rishabh

 Take time to read this post on how to compose a good SO question:

http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @garfbradaz how does this help me with my query. I understand your point but you are not helping here.

Comment: @Rishabh Im helping you compose a good querstion to the standards of SO (which is mentioned in the post). If you write good questions, you will receive good answers and replies.

Comment: @garfbradaz hope this is what you meant

Comment: @Rishabh one of the most beautiful edits i have seen - well done :)

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 4):

Try to include coordinator layout inside DrawerLayout as:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/mDrawerLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_height="match_parent
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/mNavigationView"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

then do whatever you want in coordinator layout as you implementing separately

Comment: @SıddıkAçıl can you explain what you want to know because its the above answer is simple to understand. Because the floating action button is kept in coordinate layout which is below the navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

add this to your existing code:

add this code within your class outside onCreate().

```
@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float offset){
   fabButton.setAlpha(offset);
}
```

If you don't want to switch to different FAB implementation. Use `onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float offset)` and change FAB alpha as you open the drawer. Also you could toggle its visibility inside `onDrawerClose() or onDrawerOpen()` methods too.

fab button programming is this.This is the code to set image & location and other properties of FAB.

```
fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .withDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_edit))
            .withButtonColor(0xFF2196F3)
            .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.END)
            .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
            .create();
```

try this hope it helps you out.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more.

Comment: please try this, i have guided you along with code. so first try it if it works for you i will elaborate it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/) a guide to material design implementation in your app.

Though, I would suggest making a new `Navigation drawer` activity. Go to

`File>New>Activity>Navigation Drawer Activity.`

This `activity` already comes with a FAB and a `Navigation Drawer` and already have overridden methods like `onOptionsItemSelected`(), `onNavigationItemSelected`(), etc. So all you need to do is put your layout in `content_main` file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to display my navigation from FAB Floating Action Button

```
final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.menu_button);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }
    });
```

And if you want to use Kotlin, there is a slight difference like this code

```
var drawer = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val fab = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.menu_button)
    fab.setOnClickListener {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    }
```

And this is my layout you can use one of the java or Kotlin codes above and it's working to Me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/nav_host_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav_view"/>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu_left" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```